# jQuery - Do Not Change The Value If Not Checked

Tags: jquery, if-statement, checkbox, onchange, keyup

This code was spent my whole day to fix it and there seem no way I can find, but by posting a question here.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uxTTB/)

```
     $('.git_this_similar').on('change', function(){

            if($(this).is(":checked")) {

 $(this).closest('.gscpc_right_col_inner')
.find('#git_wpost_fname, #git_wpost_imgtitle,
#git_wpost_shortdesc, #git_wpost_tags')
.attr("disabled", true);

$(this).closest('.gscpc_right_col_inner')
.find('.git_wpost_titleclass').on('keyup', function(){

$(this).closest('.gscpc_right_col_inner')
.find('#git_wpost_imgtitle, #git_wpost_shortdesc')
.val($(this).val());

var fileextension = $(this).closest('.gscpc_right_col_inner')
.find('#git_wpost_fname').val();

var lastFour = '.' + fileextension.split(".").pop();

var gitfilename = $(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(/[\W]+/g, "_") + lastFour;

$(this).closest('.gscpc_right_col_inner')
.find('#git_wpost_fname').val(gitfilename);

var git_tags = $(this).val().split(' ').join(', ');

$(this).closest('.gscpc_right_col_inner')
.find('#git_wpost_tags').val(git_tags);

});

            } else {

// turn off 'disabled' attribute    
$(this).closest('.gscpc_right_col_inner')
.find('#git_wpost_fname, #git_wpost_imgtitle, 
#git_wpost_shortdesc, #git_wpost_tags')
.attr("disabled", false);

$(this).closest('.gscpc_right_col_inner')
.find('.git_wpost_titleclass')
.on('keyup', function(){});
}

});
```

**What I actually want to do is:**

After the checkbox is clicked

```
>     IF ( the checkbox is checked)
>     {
>     Use "Post Title" field value for all input fields!
>     }
>     ELSE
>     {
>     Don't use "Post Title" field value for other input fields!
>     }
```

But what I get here is the other fields value keep following the "Post Title" value when it is changed while the checkbox is not checked.

What should I do to kill the `keyup` effect that happened when the checkbox was checked?

Comment: Can you narrow down your code

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I have edited the code to be more readable. And there is a fiddle demo with the complete codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `unbind()` the event on the else statement:

```
else {
  // turn off 'disabled' attribute    
  $(this).closest('.gscpc_right_col_inner').find('#git_wpost_fname, #git_wpost_imgtitle, #git_wpost_shortdesc, #git_wpost_tags').attr("disabled", false);
  // Unbind Keyup
  $(this).closest('.gscpc_right_col_inner').find('.git_wpost_titleclass').unbind('keyup');
}
```

Check This Demo http://jsfiddle.net/uxTTB/4/

Comment: Thank you.. another way that could do the trick is `off('keyup')`

Comment: Yep @AriSusanto and you can improve keeping this in a var `$(this).closest('.gscpc_right_col_inner');` http://jsfiddle.net/uxTTB/5/ . Just don't search any time for the same element :)